# How to copy one line from a text document to clipboard using command prompt

Tags: batch-file, text, copy, clipboard, document

I need to be able to copy one line at a time from a text document to clipboard using command prompt.

Example I have a text document like this:

> Line 1
>        Line 2
>        Line 3
>        etc...

Example: I need to be able to copy line 2 to clipboard and only line 2

What command would something like that be? or is there even a command like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "skip=1delims=" %%a IN (q27763354.txt) DO ECHO %%a|clip&GOTO done
:done

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q27763354.txt` containing your data for my testing.

the number used as "skip" is one less than the line-number you want. `skip=0` is invalid, omit the `skip=0` if you want the first line from the file.

Comment: plus one, but omitting spaces in for /f options gives me shivers .